# How to connect two buttons( dots) with a line in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I want to make a project in which I have to touch one dot and connect it with another dot and after connect it to another dot. When I connect one dot with another dot the line will create between them.

Actually when I click/ touch one dot The line will show and When I touch second dot the line will create between the two dots.

I am not able to do this yet, I am trying and searching on the net but unable to find the solution yet.

This is my need Like this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zok.android.dots&hl=en

I think this is done by UIGesture Recogniser? Or is this something else? How I can achieve this?

Any Idea or suggestions from experts would be highly welcome.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208469/draw-line-between-two-points-in-iphone

Answer (score 3):

Modify this code according to your requiements

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, touchStart.x, touchStart.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, touchEnd.x, touchEnd.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

@Nisha:

Make gloabal instances of `CGPoint` `touchStart` and `touchEnd` and get them like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
touchEnd = CGPointZero;
touchStart = CGPointZero;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
NSLog(@"start point >> %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
    touchStart = point;
}
```

}

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    touchEnd = point; 
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: what is touchStart , touchEnd is this int?

Comment: @Nisha Singh ...I have edited my answer check it..

Answer (score 1):

You can store the touched locations in two different `CGPoint` with the help of the `touchedEnded` method.

Then, when you have your two points, you can add a new UIView as subview which is aware of the two `CGPoint` and will draw a line in its `drawRect` method. Or do it in the current view, by calling `[view setNeedsDisplay]` to trigger its own drawRect method.

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050037/how-to-draw-automatic-line-between-two-tap-points-in-a-view-in-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps.

Create one subclass of UIView. Add your UIButtons on it.

Implement Touches delgates, like touchesBegan, moved, end.

Inside touchesBegan check if touch isinsideview:myButton1 then make a flag true.

EDIT:

```
UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] init];
touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(myButton1.frame, point))
    NSLog(@"Inside myButton1");
```

**Another way** to test if subview is hit by touches is

```
CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
UIView *touchedView = [self.view hitTest:pt withEvent:event];
```

inside touches moved check if flag true then drawline()... and keep checking if touches are in insideview:myButton2. call setNeedsDisplay.

Now you will get number of ways and sample code to draw line in UIView. Just apply above logic.

Comment: Sir I am able to draw line now but I am not able to do what you said. I add buttons On uiview but not able to do your 3,4 steps.

Comment: I placed my button on viewDidLoad , add on self.view , then I do Your 3rd step. Line is showing when I touch on the screen, but when I touch the button line intersect the button not touching. this line is not calling if(CGRectContainsPoint(btn1.frame, point));

Comment: your buttons should be the subviews' of View on which you are drawing.. is it so?

Comment: hitTest: this method can serve ur purpose...

Comment: @NishaSingh : this could be very helpful,just what you want.and i have used it before.... download this source code and check how they identifying touched button and draw lines...its easy to use sample code. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone

Comment: Yes sir I want to do exact like this but but little bit different. The concept is same almost. I am trying to understand code but not able to get yet because its not the tutorial and so not step by step. I am new so I think I take time to check this code. In this when I untouched the second button the line removed between the two buttons. I dont want this I want line will stay remain?

Comment: see its in their code. you use generic line drawing code, just refer that sample to detect touches and to know how to handle intersection on UIButtons.. also line wont get removed till you clear the context or remove view from superview where line is drawn...

Comment: Thanks aloot. It is good that if nobody is helping you and you are beginner then come here on stackoverflow and meet some very nice people and experts, and they will definitely help you out. Thanks sir for a great help. Can I ask you again when I get stuck?

Comment: sure..if I would be here, online then will definitely assist you in way i can...

Comment: Hi sir, Can I know that how to check line interaction in this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone example? I want when line intersect an alert will show.

Comment: they check this using  CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
  UIView *touched = [self.view hitTest:pt withEvent:event]; inside touchesMoved delegate to know which view is hit...you can see it in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible for you please get the coordinates of two button with UI touch methods. You can find the touched locations in two different `CGPoint` with the help of the `touchedEnded` method.To find touch location documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded%3awithEvent%3a)

After getting the location of `UIButtons` on your view you can draw the line between then with this method-

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what is touchStart , touchEnd is this int?

Comment: that are the coordinates of button and they are structs with two values x and y they are float values.Hope this clear now

Comment: sir not clear, I am new in iPhone. Sir how to use UIButton here?

Comment: Where? I couldn't get it.The buttons between them you want to draw line always have some coordinates on screen. Use these coordinates to draw line between them

Comment: you solved your problem or not?